# array behavior in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new in python and trying to learn machine learning. Unable to understand a line in code

```
d[df['Class label'].values == i, 0]
```

where d is a 2D array like [[1,2],[2,3],...] and df['Class label'] is a 1D array like [0,1,0,0,...]. I googled it as I get something that it is using zip function to get the x and y values from 2D array for scatter plot. But, not clear how its working.

This is taken from [link(In[13])](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/master/preprocessing/about_standardization_normalization.ipynb). Also, I am pasting the patch of code below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(6,14))

for a,d,l in zip(range(len(ax)), 
               (df[['Alcohol', 'Malic acid']].values, df_std, df_minmax),
               ('Input scale', 
                'Standardized [$N  (\mu=0, \; \sigma=1)$]', 
                'min-max scaled [min=0, max=1]')
                ):
    for i,c in zip(range(1,4), ('red', 'blue', 'green')):
        ax[a].scatter(d[df['Class label'].values == i, 0], 
                  d[df['Class label'].values == i, 1],
                  alpha=0.5,
                  color=c,
                  label='Class %s' %i
                  )
    ax[a].set_title(l)
    ax[a].set_xlabel('Alcohol')
    ax[a].set_ylabel('Malic Acid')
    ax[a].legend(loc='upper left')
    ax[a].grid()
```

Comment: Check pandas docs for the values stuff (Series vs. DataFrame) and numpy's tutorial on indexing. You are using 2 pretty complex data-structures here (pandas Series/DataFrame, numpy arrays) and should start with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

i'm only going to address this part:

```
for i,c in zip(range(1,4), ('red', 'blue', 'green')):
    ax[a].scatter(d[df['Class label'].values == i, 0], 
              d[df['Class label'].values == i, 1],
              alpha=0.5,
              color=c,
              label='Class %s' %i
              )
```

lets start at the for:

```
for i,c in zip(range(1,4), ('red', 'blue', 'green'))
```

is looping through the result of the zip.

the zip is returning the following:

```
[(1, red), (2,blue), (3, green)]
```

which is later unpacked into the variables 'i' and 'c'. So the first iteration you have

```
i = 1
c = red
```

I don't know what the rest is doing, but the part that you addressed ("d[df['Class label'].values == i, 1]") would be interpreted like this:

```
df['Class label']
```

(i'm assuming dictionary) df at the index named 'Class label'.  Now, apparently it is an object with an attribute called values, which we are giving two values in a tuple.

```
df['Class label'].values == i, 1
```

and using the return of that assignment as a key for a dictionary-like call to the object d,

```
d[df['Class label'].values == i, 1]
```

needless to say, this is terrible Python code. the variables are terribly named and you have to guess too much of what's going on. If you can, rename the variables for something that makes sense if you read it out loud. like

```
for index, color in enumerate(colors):
    delta_in_color = d[df['Class label'].values == i, 1]   # whatever this means
    ax[a].scatter(requirement_a=foo, requirement_b=delta_in_color, alpha=0.5, color=color, label=class_index)
```

Comment: @Artyro : Thanks for looking into my issue. Here df is pandas dataframe. pandas read a input file and its one of column is named as "Class label". So, it tries to get the values from column named "Class label". All the elements of this column can take three possible values 1, 2 and 3. 

Eric Ed Lohmar: gave answer but trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is `df['Class Label'].values == i` is converting the values from the `'Class Label'` column in a `pandas.DataFrame`, `df`, as a 1d array. It is then comparing each of those values to `i` and returning another 1d array which represents the locations in which the comparison comes up `True`.

```
# let's say df['Class Label'].values = [1 0 1 2 2 1 3] and i = 1
bool_array = df['Class Label'].values == 1

print(bool_array)
[True False True False False True False]
```

Next, it takes the resulting boolean array and selects all of the rows in `d` where the values are `True`. Except, since the second parameter inside the brackets is `0`, it's selecting only the values in the first column from that subset.

Let's say

```
d =  [[2  1],
      [3  4],
      [4  2],
      [1  9],
      [7  8],
      [5  3],
      [2  0]]
```

then `d[bool_array, 0]` returns `[2 4 5]` because those are the values in the first column, that match up with the `True`s in bool_array.